# Rails caching: expires_in writes to cache; how can I ignore certain params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I've been using [expires_in](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ConditionalGet/expires_in) to add a `Cache-Control` header to my responses. This way when a given user hits the same page again (e.g. when they hit back button) it won't bother hitting the server again until the cache expires.

What I did not realize is that Rails also writes a copy of the HTML to its cache if you specify `public: true`. This seems innocuous, but if you have a lot of Adsense traffic you will find that the cache quickly fills up because the `gclid` param (which is unique for each visitor) is not ignored by `expires_in`. This is especially problematic if you are using some kind of in-memory cache like Redis or Memcache.

With [caches_action](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Caching/Actions) I am able to specify a `:caches_path` argument, and I use that to ignore certain parameters, such as gclid. Is there a way to do something similar with `expires_in`?  Or is the only solution to use 'public: false' ?